# How to choose predefined install directory in a msi installer

Tags: c#, .net, windows-installer, installation

I have created msi-setup using a `Visual Studio Setup Project` and an `Installer Project` for my application and it works fine. My application is successfully installed and can be executed correct.

Now I'd like to add a dialog in the `Setup Project` where the user should be able to choose the directory(location) where the application is installed. I know that there is a separate dialog for choosing the dictionary but the user should not have the permission to install the application where ever he/she wants.

So I thought of the Dialog `RadioButtons` where the user can choose between some predefined directories.

Is there a way to handle this?
E.g. getting the value of the choosen button in the Installer Project and handle it there? Or setting the `DefaultLocation` of the `Application Folder` to the value of the radio button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You found the answer by yourself. The **Application Folder** is known by *Windows Installer* via the [TARGETDIR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372064%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property. Note that some installers use another property for the installation directory (which overwrites *TARGETDIR*).

To change the TARGETDIR folder **from a radio control** you need two things:

- make sure the *RadioButtonGroup* has the property TARGETDIR
- on the *Next* button, have a **SetTargetPath** control event for TARGETDIR

You should also have a default value for your location. That can be solved with a Custom Action type **51** scheduled for execution before *CostInitialize* on both *InstallUISequence* and *InstallExecuteSequence*.

Cheers

Comment: @ mteodor thanks for the answer. I know that i can call the TARGETDIR property in my Installer, but i have no idea how i could set this TARGETDIR to the value of the choosen Radio Button. Is it possible to get this value in my Installer?

Comment: Thanks for your help! I just had to set the ButtonProperty of the Radio Buttons Dialog to TARGETDIR and it worked.